# Calculating the fastest routes and some points on the same time

Tags: java, algorithm, routes, gps, gis

I have two drivers and each driver has a set of about 15 locations where they need to drive to on a single day. Calculating the shortest route for both drivers is not the problem (using a matrix routing api).

The drivers can have the same location in their route. And if they are the same, then they both need to be there at the same time. So I need to make software that calculates the fastest route but sometimes the drivers need to be at the same location at the same time.

My question: How can I make this software, and are there any libraries I can use?

Example with 6 locations (software needs to calculate 15):

Locations of driver A:

- 51.873215,4.606388 (start)
- 51.7498817,4.3705702
- 51.8395805,4.3535099 (same as driver B)
- 51.8961411,4.4681101
- 52.0041504,4.48627
- 52.061006,4.486609 (end)

Locations of driver B:

- 51.873215,4.606388 (start)
- 51.7914314,4.6571202
- 51.8422203,4.33954
- 51.8670325,4.3453742
- 51.8395805,4.3535099 (same as driver A)
- 51.7084897,4.6603792 (end)

The software needs to sort the coordinates to have the fastest route. But the drivers needs to be at the same location on the same time at this location: 51.8395805,4.3535099

Expected output driver A: https://www.google.nl/maps/dir/51.873215,4.606388/51.8395805,4.3535099/51.7498817,4.3705702/51.8961411,4.4681101/52.0041504,4.48627/52.061006,4.486609/

Expected output driver B:
https://www.google.nl/maps/dir/51.873215,4.606388/51.8395805,4.3535099/51.8422203,4.33954/51.8670325,4.3453742/51.7914314,4.657120251.7084897,4.6603792/

Comment: "Calculating the shortest route for both drivers is not the problem" - It seems that no one told me that the ["Travelling salesman problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) is now solved.

Comment: @FlorentBayle Actually, for 15 location it is pretty easy to solve TSP, DP solution will be quick enough, and probably even branch and bound techniques for naive solution.

Comment: do they start travelling at the same time?

Comment: Yes, they start traveling at the same time.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample input and expected output, in order to clarify the problem?

Comment: I have edited my post with an example.

Comment: I think that using [constraint programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming#Constraint_programming_libraries_for_imperative_programming_languages) would be a profitable approach. Look for tutorial material on applying CP to the traveling salesman or vehicle routing problem and adapt it to your unique constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [jsprit](http://jsprit.github.io/).

If you determine the time windows where both drivers meet each other at a specified location a priori, then it is easy to model (just look at the 'Simple Example' in the wiki to figure out how you model and solve such a problem). 
Time windows are defined as follows:

```
Service.Builder.newInstance("service").setTimeWindow(TimeWindow.newInstance(10,20)) ...
```

If you do not want to set time windows in advance, you need to learn how to setup your own states and constraints. It is partly documented [here](https://github.com/jsprit/jsprit/wiki/Walkthrough---Constraints) and in a number of examples and the mailing list.

To consider your shortest routes from one location to another (from your matrix routing api), just use core.util.VehicleRoutingTransportCostMatrix (jsprit.examples.CostMatrixExample illustrates it) and assign the matrix to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks similar to a vrp problem. You can break the problem into smaller problem, for example consider the location where the drivers has to meet as a depot.  Then you can use a vrp algorithm with this constraint.